# npm run dev, shows error - return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

Tags: reactjs

I am using following command to create new project

```
npm create vite@latest ( 
name: » react3,  framework: React variant: JavaScript)
 
    cd react3
    npm install
    npm run dev
```

When running **npm run dev** the following error shows

Platform
Windows Home 10 64bit, Version 1909, Node.js v20.9.0

```
> react3@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\D:\react3\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react3\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

**Node.js v20.9.0**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569907/error-in-react-vite-project-due-to-rollup-dependency-module-not-found)

Comment: Yes, Install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported" help in my case. Based on my architecture I installed vc_redist.x64.exe, thank you for your question

Comment: please confirm to close the question as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this solved it. install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64).
[source](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4297)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this solved: lerna/lerna#3612 (comment)
tl;dr, Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) missing

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).