# Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, vite

I am facing an error in react vite project.

snippet from package.json

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"vite": "^5.0.0",
"vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0",
```

The error is :

> D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64
> throw new Error(
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-x64-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828).
> Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
> at requireWithFriendlyError (D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64:9)
> at Object. (D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:73:48)
> 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
> at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:345:17)
> at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:294:7)
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
> at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24) {
> [cause]: Error: The specified module could not be found.
> \?\D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
> at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1473:18)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
> at requireWithFriendlyError (D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:62:10)
> at Object. (D:\React\ACL\Acl28\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:73:48)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32) {
> code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
> }
> }
>
> Node.js v20.10.0

========
vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({

 build: {
     outDir: 'build',
 },
 plugins: [
     reactRefresh(),
     svgrPlugin({
         svgrOptions: {
             icon: true,
         },
     }),
 ],

})
```

Please help in resolving the problem

The project is working fine in another system which has windows 11 as I my system has. Even if I copied whole working project including node-modules folder from another system into my system , the problem persists.
The node version is 20 in my system. Another system has node version 16.16

I am expecting to run my react-vite project properly.

Answer (score 3):

Add to your dependencies in your package.json: "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "^4.9.2"

That's all you need

Comment: This can't be installed on unix or windows env. Modifying package.json seems the best option I have added an answer about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same problem since yesterday... I solved it by downloading the most recent Visual C++ Redistributable. I saw a lot of guys in another forum that also got it.

You can download it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

Because you lack of @rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu dependency

In **package.json** you add this dependency as a optinal. And then you run it at windown so ok, run it at linux still ok

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.6.1"
  }
```

Comment: I had the same issue with Cloudflare Pages deployment and this answer helped me resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You can try these to solve this issue. These steps worked for me :

1. Install Microsoft C++ Redistributable 2015.
2. Remove `package-lock.json`.
3. Delete `node_modules` folder.
4. Restart the machine.
5. Run `npm install`.
6. Run `npm run dev` if you're using vite.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happens because Rollup uses the Visual Studio Redistributable to make native calls ([source](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4297#issuecomment-1817549776)). If you don't have a Visual Studio redistributable installed, install one from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist for your platform. After doing that, try to run package installation or whatever npm command you were trying to run again (you may need to do [some extra steps](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/3612#issuecomment-1538380963) to refresh things).

Rollup itself has recently made a change to add a more friendly error message about this. See [Add friendly error for missing MSVC redistributable #5284](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/5284).

Answer (score 0):

this actually happended to me
try to uninstall node **v20.10.0** you have now and download node version **v18.12.0**

Comment: The question mentions that they have already tried node v20 and v16. Why do you think it would be useful for them to try v18 ? Also it might have only been a fix for you because you are using different versions of npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

Its **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported** issue

Based on my architecture I download & Install the following file

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.arm64.exe

Comment: what does this add on top of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of good answers on this github thread on the vite  [github repository](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/15167) it offered two alternative on the package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
  },
```

alternative:

```
"overrides": {
  "vite": {
    "rollup": "npm:@rollup/wasm-node"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It was fixed by updating node.js; try running:

```
nvm install latest
```

Use the command below to make sure that you are running the desired version of node

```
nvm use vA.B.C
```

vA.B.C = the version number that you'd like to use.

Once the new version of node is installed, delete the `node_modules` package and the `package-lock.json`

Run the `npm install` command and try running the app.